# Convert Complex formatted Word document to sane html

Tags: html, ms-word, ms-office

I have a lot of text data snippets consisting of multiple nested lists, all combined into a single word document that needs to be saved to a database field for eventual rendering in a browser.  I'm willing to cut and paste into the database, but I need to convert from Word formatting to simple, clean html.

for example, in Word I have:

> This question has two parts, for a total of 6 marks

```
1. Answer should cover
   - List item (2 marks)
   - List item (2 marks)
   - List item (2 marks)
2. And logically tie the items together (2 marks)
```

What I need is:

```
<p> This question has two parts, for a total of 6 marks </p>
<ol type="1">
<li> Answer should cover <ul> <li>List item (2 marks)</li>...</ul>
etc.
```

Is there any simple way doing this?

It seems that Word **Save as Webpage** needs about as much work cleaning it up as doing it all by hand.

Pasting into Visual Studio design window isn't much better.

Comment: Sigh... Always Microsoft and problems. They go together like peanut butter and jelly.

Comment: Your comment isn't helpful, but it expresses my inner soul beautifully.

Comment: Who says comments have to be helpful?